# why pagination is not showing ? django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, pagination, frameworks

```
def allProductCat(request, c_slug=None):
    c_page = None
    products_list = None
    if c_slug is not None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=c_slug)
        products_list = Product.objects.all().filter(category=c_page, available=True)
    else:
        products_list = Product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    paginator = Paginator(products_list, 6)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, "category.html", {'category': c_page, 'product': products})
```

// Code for Html //

```
<div class="mx-auto">
    {% if product.paginator.num_page %}
    <hr>
    <div class="text-center">
        {% for pg in product.paginator.page_range %}
             <a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm {% if product.number == pg %} active {% endif %}">{{pg}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

when i add all these codes pagination doesnt shows up anything when i type the links to next page manually its working perfectly i dont understand whats wrong in this code, also these div doesnt shows anything inside it when i type anything...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

====== views.py =======

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def HomeView(request):
    show_data = VehicleModel.objects.all() # Queryset For pagiantion
    # Pagination code start
    paginator = Paginator(show_data, 3, orphans=1)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    show_data = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    # Pagination code end
    context = {'page_number':page_number}
    return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)
```

======= in HTML ==========

```
# <!-- Pagination Block with page number  -->
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row float-right ">
        <span class="m-0 p-0">

            {% if show_data.has_previous %} # <!-- For Previous Button -->
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{show_data.previous_page_number}}&ok=#ok">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}


            <span>{% for pg in show_data.paginator.page_range %} # <!-- For Page Numbers Buttons -->
                {% if show_data.number == pg %}
                <a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                    <span class="badge">{{pg}}</span>
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
                    <span class="badge">{{pg}}</span>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}</span>

            {% if show_data.has_next %} # <!-- For Next Button -->
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{show_data.next_page_number}}&ok=#ok">Next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```